# make wcf dataservice generate entities with virtual properties

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, interface, virtual

We reference a wcf data service which we cannot modify.

It is added to our project as a service reference.

When this is done, the entity classes get generated.

We would like for the generated properties to be virtual.

E.g.

> public virtual string Name {get;set;}

It would also be cool if they could be made to implement an interface containing the properties they have.

I plan on augmenting them with Castle.DynamicProxy.

From my point of view, either implementing an ifc, or making the properties virtual in the generated classes should not interfere with data transfer as this is strictly client side.

So, is it possible to have the service generated entities have virtual properties? Or for them to implement an interface containing their property list, and how?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: :) Yes, edited the question to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to generate virtual members with WCF.

One solution could be to use an interface instead. You can take advantage of the fact that the generated classes are marked as partial, which avoids the need for editing generated code and hence having your modifications being overwritten when you re-generate the code.

The solution to this question may be useful:

[How can I mark the methods in a WCF client proxy generated class as virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235345/how-can-i-mark-the-methods-in-a-wcf-client-proxy-generated-class-as-virtual)